# How to generate a distinct average of lots of data in Pig Latin?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have a large data set of rental listings that I want to generate the average price for each city based on the number of bedrooms. I have the following types of rows:

`{( city: 'New York', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 1000.00 ),
  ( city: 'New York', num_bedrooms: 2, price: 2000.00 ),
  ( city: 'New York', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 2000.00 ),
  ( city: 'Chicago', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 4000.00 ),
  ( city: 'Chicago', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 1500.00 )}`

Using Pig, I want to get results in the following format:

`{( city: 'New York', 1: 1500.00, 2: 2000.00),
 ( city: 'Chicago', 1: 2750.00 )}`

Alternatively, I could deal with this too:

`{( city: 'New York', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 1500.00),
 ( city: 'New York', num_bedrooms: 2, price: 2000.00),
 ( city: 'Chicago', num_bedrooms: 1, price: 2750.00 )}`

My plan is to create bar charts using this data with the number of bedrooms along the X axis, and the price on the Y axis for a given city. I have been able to group by city and number of bedrooms and then average that, but I don't know how to put the data in the format I want. So far this is what I have:

`D = GROUP blah BY (city, num_bedrooms);
C = FOREACH D GENERATE blah.city, blah.num_bedrooms, AVG(blah.price);`

However this causes the city and num_bedrooms to be repeated for each time they appear!

Comment: The objective can be achieved using nested for each. Have suggested two approaches in the solution, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input :**

```
New York,1,1000.00
New York,2,2000.00
New York,1,2000.00
Chicago,1,4000.00
Chicago,1,1500.00
```

**Approach 1 :**

**Pig Script :**

```
rental_data = LOAD 'rental_data.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray, num_bedrooms: long, price:double);
rental_data_grp_city = GROUP rental_data BY (city);
rental_kpi = FOREACH rental_data_grp_city {
    one_bed_room = FILTER rental_data BY num_bedrooms==1;
    two_bed_room = FILTER rental_data BY num_bedrooms==2;
    GENERATE group AS city, AVG(one_bed_room.price) AS one_bed_price, AVG(two_bed_room.price) AS tow_bed_price;
};
```

**Output : DUMP rental_kpi :**

```
 (Chicago,2750.0,)
 (New York,1500.0,2000.0)
```

**Approach 2 :**

**Pig Script :**

```
rental_data = LOAD 'rental_data.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray, num_bedrooms: long, price:double);
rental_data_grp_city = GROUP rental_data BY (city,num_bedrooms);
rental_kpi = FOREACH rental_data_grp_city {
    prices_bag = rental_data.price;
    GENERATE group.city AS city, group.num_bedrooms AS num_bedrooms, AVG(prices_bag) AS price; 
}
```

**Output : DUMP rental_kpi :**

```
(Chicago,1,2750.0)
(New York,2,2000.0)
(New York,1,1500.0)
```